# Magento 2.3 - Mandatory Custom Section add in Create account page

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account

[image]

I have added the checkbox to my sign-up page. but I want that every user should check the button to create an account. I have tried to make it with Javascript.
I am using Magento 2.3.0
Here is the code.

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" required id="checkBoxRequired">
        <a href="#">Privacy & Policy</a>
    </input>
    <span id="span"></span>
</div>

function validateForm() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkBoxRequired");
    if (checkbox.checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "*Checking the checkbox";
        document.getElementById("span").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("span").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
}
```

***I have added onsubmit="return validateForm()" inside begining form tag!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to overwrite `register.phtml` file in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/form/register.phtml

and add the code below after **confirmarion password** field

```
<div class="field choice privacy_policy">
    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Privacy & Policy')) ?>" value="1" id="privacy_policy"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getPrivacyPolicy()) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}">
    <label for="privacy_policy" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Privacy & Policy')) ?></span></label>
</div>
```

[image]
You don't need to add any custom JavaScript validation

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The classes you added, is that mandatory or I can add as I want.